# How to encrypt tomcat passwords

Tags: tomcat8

I have been using tomcat 8 version. How do we encrypt the tomcat passwords in server.xml file.

I have tried using digest. It didn't work for me. Is there any other way to encrypt the passwords?

Answer (score -1):

To encrypt the password for Tomcat 8, you can use the Digest Utility provided by Tomcat to enhance security. Here are the steps to encrypt the password:

1.Open a command-line terminal.

2.Navigate to the bin directory of your Tomcat installation. This is the bin folder under your Tomcat installation directory.

3.Run the following command:

```
./digest.sh -a SHA-256
```

For Windows systems, use digest.bat:

```
 digest.bat -a SHA-256
```

This will prompt you to enter a password and then generate the encrypted password. SHA-256 is a hash algorithm, and you can choose other algorithms such as MD5 or SHA-1 based on your requirements.

4.Copy the generated encrypted password.

5.Open the tomcat-users.xml file and replace the plain-text password with the encrypted password in the corresponding  element:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="admin" password="{encrypted password}" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

6.Save the file.

7.Restart the Tomcat server.

Now, your password is stored in an encrypted form in the tomcat-users.xml file. This method is helpful for improving the security of passwords. Note that choosing an appropriate hash algorithm depends on your security requirements, and newer algorithms are generally more secure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: Is there any other way apart from using digest. I tried using digest but it didn't work for me.